# codeigniter datamapper

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.0 and MySQL. I want to display a horizontal data row as a vertical one. When I fetch a single row from the database and echo it, it looks like

```
----------------------------------------
id    | name   | address | email       |
----------------------------------------
1     | Foo    | Bar     | foo@bar.com |
----------------------------------------
```

I have used CodeIgniters table library to generate the above table. instead of this, I want it show like this:

```
------
id : 1
name: foo
address : bar
email: foo@bar.com
-------------------
```

How do I do this with CodeIgniter 2.1.0?

Answer (score 3):

if u are using a template view, then this is the better procedure
example code:
view->template:

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header');?>
<?php $this->load->view($main_content);?>
<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer');?>
```

model:

```
function detail()
{
 $this->db->where('id',$this -> session -> userdata('id'));
 $query=$this->db->get('user');
 $row=$query->row_array();
 return $row;
}
```

controller:

```
$this->load->model('my_model');
$this->my_model->detail();
$data=array(
 'id'=>$query['id'],
 'name'=>$query['name'],
 'address'=>$query['address'],
 'email'=>$query['email']
);
$data['main_content'] = 'your_view';
$this->load->view('my_view',$data);
```

view:

```
<div>
id : <?php echo $id;?><br/>
name: <?php echo $name;?><br/>
address: <?php echo $address;?><br/>
email: <?php echo $email;?>
</div>
```

it is always preferred and assumed good practice to use templating for your code view.